# Why do I get an error on buttons.forEach(function(button) in one exercise and not in another similar exercise

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

I have two similar exercises and in the first exercises I don't get a problem:

Exercise that doesn't give a problem in the `forEach`

```
// Change background color (basic)
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('main button');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

buttons.forEach(function (button) {
    console.log('textContent', button.textContent);
    button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        console.log('Je hebt geklikt op', button.textContent);
        body.style.backgroundColor = button.textContent;
    });
});
```

In the second exercise I was looking why I get a NULL when I use the selector '.border-gray'.
At a certain point he started to complain and gave me this error Uncaught TypeError: buttons.forEach is not a function at bgcolor_advanced.js:5. At first he didn't complain about it and in the first exercise, it is exactly the same and it works. Why it gives a problem in the second?

Exercise where the `forEach` gives a problem

```
const buttons = document.querySelector('main button');
const klasse = document.querySelector('div.border-gray');
console.log(buttons);
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    console.log('textContent', button.textContent);
    klasse.style.backgroundColor = button.textContent;
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log('Je hebt geklikt op', button.textContent);
        klasse.style.backgroundColor = button.textContent;
    });
});
```

Second question is why I cannot succeed to get something out of "const klasse". Always says it is undefined.

This is my html:

```
<main class="container">
        <h1>Change background color <small>advanced</small></h1>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="primary">lightsalmon</button>
            <button type="button" class="primary">palegreen</button>
            <button type="button" class="primary">#49eae7</button>
            <button type="button" class="primary">hotpink</button>
            <button type="button" class="secondary">reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="border-gray">
```

Thankyou very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Please don't use images for your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.querySelectorAll() returns a NodeList of elements, even if there is only one matching element.
.querySelector() returns the first matching element.

In your first exercise, you correctly use .querySelectorAll() to get a list of all of the buttons, which you then iterate over with .forEach()
In your second exercise, you use .querySelector(), which only returns one button. Therefore, when you try to use .forEach() to iterate over it, you get an error.

Similarly

Your call to:

```
klasse.textContent
```

is trying to retrieve the textContent attribute from a *list* of elements. That attribute is only available on individual elements. Iterate through the list and access the attribute that way - **or** - if you only have one element with class ".border-gray", switch to .querySelector()

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou very much. Everything is solved. Just have to see how I have to ask and include images, because that I didn't understand very well. Thankyou for your help. Sometimes you need more eyes to see the mistakes :-).

Comment: Very true. I myself have missed many simple errors. Sometimes, I even catch the error while asking for help figuring out what is wrong. Keep going! :)